# Match all in string but pattern

Tags: regex

I have a problem where I'm looking to match all in string but a pattern.

Testcase strings are:

```
Something[else]
Something
```

I want to match "Something" in both cases, excluding "[else]" where [else] can contain any character e.g. [.*]

`.*?(?=\[.*\])` would match the first case but not the last. I can't get my head around this.

Comment: Please post more examples, and be more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to match all up to the square bracket.

Something like `^[^\[]+`

Regex explained:

```
^          # Beginning of string
[^\[]+     # All characters up to (but not) the first '['
```

Answer (score -1):

`^(Something).*/$1/` should work.

[Example (with explanation)](https://www.regex101.com/r/oE5oK0/2)

Comment: Do us a favor and give an explanation for why it should work.

Comment: @newbiedoodle Check my answer now (needed a few seconds just to make the example :) )

Comment: Can you write the explanation in the answer, instead of linking it? Your answer should be self-sufficient.

Comment: @newbiedoodle This is a fairly standard answer for regexes. Regex101 has much better explinations than I can make, and their links wont rot. Moreover, my answer (the regex itself) is self-sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I think perhaps you misunderstand my testcases. This is perhaps a better example:  
"Something[else]" or "Some other thing"

Comment: @Dyvel So what do you want to match in that case? And please update your question with some more clear examples

Comment: @DavidGrinberg You're not explaining for someone who's seen regexes before. You're explaining for someone who is a beginning programmer and hasn't seen regexes, and so needs an explanation even for things you consider very basic. You can literally copy and paste. Actually, give me ten minutes: I'll do it for you.